# is it possible to override the c++ operator<< for a struct in a header file?

Tags: c++, header, ostream

I am trying to print out the fields in a struct by overriding operator<<. This works fine if I place the override in a cpp file, however I would like to have it in my header file.

However when I do, I get the error:

```
  multiple definition of `operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, test)'
```

Is it possible to have in the header file?

```
test.h
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
struct test{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};


  std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const test& t){
       o <<"{ " << t.a << " }" << endl;
       return o;
  }

#endif
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with any function, if you define it in a header, make it inline:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const test& t)
^^^^^^
```

This relaxes the One Definition Rule, allowing a definition in any translation unit that includes the header.

Comment: Mike that worked, however when I use cout<<t<<endl; The program is returning a system address and not { *t.a }. Is it defaulting to the default definition and not the override?

where I have test t; t.a = 5;

Comment: @Sam: If you have another question, please ask another question, with a complete program that demonstrates whatever problem you're having.