# Problem iterating through vector in inline stream overload

Tags: c++, vector, stringstream

I'm attempting to use an overloaded stream to output the contents of a map of structs referenced by ints to screen.  The map contains a vector of structs.  The code is below:

```
typedef struct{
    int iDetail;
    string sDetail;
} AlarmDetail;

typedef struct{
    int iNumber;
    string sName;
    vector<AlarmDetail> vDetails;
} AlarmInfo;

inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const AlarmDetail& DataStruct)
{
    stream << "{ iDetail: " << DataStruct.iDetail << ", ";
    stream << "sDetail: " << DataStruct.sDetail << " }";

    return stream;
}

inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const AlarmInfo& DataStruct)
{
    stream << "{ iNumber: " << DataStruct.iNumber << ", ";
    stream << "sName: " << DataStruct.sName << ", ";
    stream << "vDetails: [";

    // loop over the vector of alarm details and output each of them
    for(vector<AlarmDetail>::iterator VectorIterator = DataStruct.vDetails.begin(); VectorIterator != DataStruct.vDetails.end(); ++VectorIterator)
    {
        stream << (*VectorIterator) << ", ";
    }

    stream << "] }";

    return stream;
}
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
../main.cpp:47:78: error: conversion from ‘std::vector<AlarmDetail>::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const AlarmDetail*, std::vector<AlarmDetail> >}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<AlarmDetail>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<AlarmDetail*, std::vector<AlarmDetail> >}’ requested
```

What am I missing?

I'm pretty sure that I have similar code working other places not inside an inline operator, is this the problem?

I followed the two stack overflow posts and solutions below for the basic structure of the stream operator overloads:
[overloading-with-a-struct-no-class-cout-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719136/overloading-with-a-struct-no-class-cout-style)
[is-it-possible-to-override-the-c-operator-for-a-struct-in-a-header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567010/is-it-possible-to-override-the-c-operator-for-a-struct-in-a-header-file)

Comment: The vector is const because you pass AlarmInfo as const reference, so you need to use the `const_iterator`.

Comment: This is why `auto` is so useful.  Just use `auto VectorIterator = DataStruct.vDetails.begin()` and not care about the actual type.

Comment: @t.niese Well, sure enough, const_iterator did it.  Didn't even realize such a thing existed, thanks so much!

Comment: @NathanOliver how oh how have I not known about auto?  I've been using the C++11 structures for threading and mutexing for a while but I didn't know about auto, that is awesome!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm not sure how you missed it.  IT should be one of the very first things you learn about in C++11.  Do you know about ranged based for loops or `decltype`?